# 2 Doubts about threads from book "Modern Operating System" by Tanenbaum

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

I was reading [Operating Systems By Tanenbaum](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25075&seqNum=3)

1. Doubt 1

where I found this paragraph

> So far we have seen two possible designs: a multithreaded Web server and a single-threaded Web server. Suppose that threads are not available but the system designers find the performance loss due to single threading unacceptable. If a nonblocking version of the read system call is available, a third approach is possible. When a request comes in, the one and only thread examines it. If it can be satisfied from the cache, fine, but if not, a nonblocking disk operation is started.
> The server records the state of the current request in a table and then goes and gets the next event. The next event may either be a request for new work or a reply from the disk about a previous operation. If it is new work, that work is started. If it is a reply from the disk, the relevant information is fetched from the table and the reply processed. With nonblocking disk I/O, a reply probably will have to take the form of a signal or interrupt.

It says that it will start a disk read and return back .
I have a weird doubt, if it is single threaded, who is actually running the disk read operation ? Does it not require someone to manage it in a separate thread/process(which is also not possible because only one thread is available).(I have read in nodejs that underlying threads in thread pool manage this).

2. Doubt 2

> Instead of thinking about interrupts, timers, and context switches, we can think about parallel processes.

What does author mean by this ?

Comment: Why did you tag Node.js?

Comment: (I have a note about nodejs in the post itself) because It is a similar system but with only difference where the underlying work is carried out by worker threads.. but here on the contrary author speaks about exactly one thread but still work being carried out ...so only tagged it .. should I remove ?

Comment: @thefourtheye Is it misleading ? shall I remove the tag ?

Comment: Yes please. If your question is not directly related to node.js, its not better not to have that tag

Comment: ok thanks.. removing it now ... done

Comment: You do realize that *node.js* is not an operating system, right?

Comment: yes I do ... but I understand your point .. nodejs(user space application) will not have access to everything(dma for eg) that the operating system(kernel) has access to ...

Comment: Do you realize that being single-threaded does not necessarily means being single-process? I mean there can be WebListener.exe which registers client attempts, ClienFactory.exe, which spawns ClientHandler.exe for each and every client and multiple instances of ClientHandler.exe which handle individual connections. All of them are single thread processes, but running in a parallel sense.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is being handled by the I/O hardware: you send a command to it, telling it what read/write you want done, and it does it using distinct hardware, signaling the main processor when it is finished (which can then respond as appropriate).
2. This means to think about things at a higher level; those other things are implementation details as to how to achieve the desired parallelism.

Comment: if possible can you share references or good articles on this ? especially related to IO hardware parallelism..